# Database of insect sounds

Tags: entomology, database, research-tools

I was thinking last night as I laid listening to the loud insects at night here in Georgia, that I wanted to be able to hear the bug sounds people listen to all over the world. Could not find much online but maybe I’m bad at searching. Is there a database of insect sounds?

Comment: Not surre absolutely, but iNaturalist often has sound files, as does BugGuide.